# Haskell about isDigit

Tags: haskell

My function is "demo :: String -> String", I want to use isDigit to solve it. If my input is "6", my output should be "6". If my input is "Aris", my output is "Aris". How can I do That. Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Er, `demo = id`?

Comment: Not sure you mean what you write. But in the case you mean it, the simplest answer would be `id`

Comment: Or `demo a = a` in case the asker isn't comfortable with first class functions (although they should be soon)

Answer (score 1):

As written, your specification can be met by:

```
demo = id
```

and

```
demo "6" = "6"
demo "Aris" = "Aris"
```